# Within a D3 scatter chart, how can I anchor an image of variable size to the centre of a coordinate/point

Tags: d3.js

I have realised whilst creating my scatter chart that the images are appended to the 0,0 point of the co-ordinate.   After reading up on this I've found that I can centre the image by making use of 'transform' and adjusting the x and y point by half that of the image's height and width

eg

```
var logosize = 50

//image
svg.selectAll(".image")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("svg:image")
  .attr("x", xMap)
  .attr("y", yMap)
  .attr("width", logosize)
  .attr("height", logosize)
  .attr('transform', 'translate('+ -logosize/2 +',' + -logosize/2 + ')'   )
  .attr("xlink:href", function(d) {
    return d.brand_image;
  })
```

Result1:

[image: Image1]

This works as expected, however, I need the image size to come from a field in the dataset called 'logosize'

If I try updating the logosize variable to a function that gets the logosize field then the transform no longer works in the same way:

eg

```
var logosize = function(d) {
        return d.logosize
    };

//image
    svg.selectAll(".image")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("svg:image")
      .attr("x", xMap)
      .attr("y", yMap)
      .attr("width", logosize)
      .attr("height", logosize)
      .attr('transform', 'translate('+ -logosize/2 +',' + -logosize/2 + ')'   )
      .attr("xlink:href", function(d) {
        return d.brand_image;
      })
```

Result2:

[image: image2]

I'm sure i'm probably missing something very obvious once again but any help would be appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you changed `logosize` to a function,  `.attr('transform', 'translate('+ -logosize/2 +',' + -logosize/2 + ')'   )` doesn't make sense anymore (dividing a function by two?). I suggest not naming your function with the same name as your `logosize` number variable to avoid confusion.

Here is an example using just inline anonymous functions:

```
//image
    svg.selectAll(".image")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("svg:image")
      .attr("x", xMap)
      .attr("y", yMap)
      .attr("width", function(d) { return d.logosize; })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return d.logosize; })
      .attr('transform', function(d) { return 'translate('+ -d.logosize/2 +',' + -d.logosize/2 + ')'; }   )
      .attr("xlink:href", function(d) {
        return d.brand_image;
      })
```